# What is the best place to hook a graphical pop up on accessing a file in linux?

Tags: linux

I need to scan a file while it is being opened in Linux and look for some patterns.
If the pattern is found I need to send a message to the user-space and have it shown to the user, e.g. a graphical pop-up, that explains that the operation failed because a virus was detected.

I am able to scan the file and search for the pattern by hooking my open system call in Linux.
But, I am not able to figure out a way to send a message to the user-space and have it shown to the user, e.g. a graphical pop-up, that explains that the operation failed because a virus was detected.

Could someone please suggest some way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

`inotify` can be used to poll for events on files/inodes.
`alert` aliased command can be used to generate UI/graphical alert/notification

ex: alert "something has happened on "

`alert` is alias to `notify-send`